# Escaping ampersand (&) and plus sign (+) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, special-characters, sign, ampersand

I am trying to perform a `Set-ADUser`command to Active Directory in order to update the *mobile* and *title* attribute as below :

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "UID1234" -Mobile "+2345678" -Server \$domainController[0] -Credential $mycred;
```

This command goes through. Unfortunately, the plus sign (+) is being replaced by a space in the account.

I also want to perform the same command to update the *title* attribute :

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "UID1234" -Title "Employee & Manager" -Server \$domainController[0] -Credential $mycred;
```

Here, I am getting the following error : 
`The string is missing the terminator \"` because of the ampersand (&) character that is not understood as a proper character as it is generally used for calling variables.

For both of these cases, I understand that there should be a way to escape these characters but I was not successful by using escapers such as backslash () or back-single quote (`).

Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: PowerShell allows `&` unescaped in strings; the fact that `&` is also the call operator isn't relevant. PowerShell does not use the backslash for escaping but the backtick, so whatever mangling happens is the result of the cmdlet passing the string to AD with whatever mechanism that uses. Try `\2B` and `\26` to escape `+` and `&`, respectively (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for the advice, unfortunately, your suggestion did not work for me. Also thanks for the added common knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions. First, try using a single quote around the text as opposed to double quotes. PowerShell will treat any text between single quotes as literal.

Example:

```
$i = 10
Write-Host 'The value of i is $i'
> The value of i is $i
```

Secondly,

If you wish to leave the double quotes, which you will have to do for this to work, place a ` (Backtick/grave accent character) before the "&" and "+" signs.

```
"`+2345678"
"Employee `& Manager"
```

Comment: I did try to use single quotes around the text. Unfortunately it did not help. The plus sign (+) is still replaced by a whitespace. I tried the backtick but this solution did not help as well.

Comment: Regarding the use of the backtick with the ampersand, I am getting `The string is missing the terminator`. I will also check internally if there I can get additional assistance.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you are receiving? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To escape ampersands sign, you could try to wrap it in double quote e.g. 'Employee "&" Manager'
Ref https://github.com/arcanecode/PowerShell/issues/1